# C++ - Live screen capture, what approach should be used?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, remote-desktop, screen-capture

I am currently writing a C++ application in Qt allowing Remote Desktop Connection, just like Teamviewer except that it will be using QTcpSocket.

As I need to make it Cross Platform, using Windows headers isn't an option here. However, the code will be flexible enough to provide different screen capture implementations for later.

My question here is which approach should be used.

1. Take a screeshot, send it to the socket. [More data over network]
2. Take a screeshot, compare it to the previous screen capture, and send only the differences. For exemple sending Square blocks of let's say 64x64 pixels. [Less data over network, requires Pixel looping...]
3. A direct stream of the screen ? Possible ? [More data over network].

Thanks in advance :) ! Trying to figure out the best solution to make it smooth ! :)

Comment: You need to use Image processing for number 2.

Comment: Your first and second idea are basically poor man's video streaming.

Comment: As for performance, you will never achieve anything decent bandwith and performance wise without building a custom low-level protocol yourself that is tailored for the specific operating system (which is what Teamviewer does). Video streaming, which is probably the fastest and most-efficient bandwith-wise of your listed ideas would probably consume 5 to 15 times more bandwith than that. AV1 might be the best choice for the video streaming, if you can control the hardware that you can use and if you can wait until such hardware is on the market.